# TreeSet throws nullpointer exception when using custom comparator

Tags: java, set

I got an error msg when I trying to remove a specific element in treeset (not null). I'm not sure why this happened, and I tried to use contains to check if there has the same element in the set already which would work fine. The exception throws when calling reset method.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at line 55, Leaderboard$1.compare
  at line 52, Leaderboard$1.compare
  at line 374, java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator
  at line 343, java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry
  at line 601, java.base/java.util.TreeMap.remove
  at line 276, java.base/java.util.TreeSet.remove
  at line 86, Leaderboard.reset
  at line 71, __Driver__.__helperSelectMethod__
  at line 91, __Driver__.__helper__
  at line 112, __Driver__.main
```

> Here is my code:

```
class Leaderboard {
    TreeSet<Integer> TS;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> HS = new HashMap<>();
    public Leaderboard() {
        TS = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Integer>(){
           @Override
            public int compare(Integer a, Integer b){
                if(HS.get(a).equals(HS.get(b))){
                    return Integer.compare(a, b);
                }
                return HS.get(a).compareTo(HS.get(b));
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void addScore(int playerId, int score) {
        HS.put(playerId, HS.getOrDefault(playerId, 0) + score);
        TS.add(playerId);
        TreeSet<Integer> test = TS;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> test2 = HS;
    }
    
    public int top(int K) {
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = TS.iterator();

        int res = 0;
        while(K > 0 && iterator.hasNext()){
            res += HS.get(iterator.next());
            K--;
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    public void reset(int playerId) {
        Integer id = new Integer(playerId); //tried, not work
        System.out.println(HS.containsKey(id)); // true        
        System.out.println(TS.contains(id)); // true
        HS.remove(id);
        TS.remove(id);
    }
}

/**
 * Your Leaderboard object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * Leaderboard obj = new Leaderboard();
 * obj.addScore(playerId,score);
 * int param_2 = obj.top(K);
 * obj.reset(playerId);
 */
```

Comment: Are you certain that `HS.get(a)` never returns null in your `compare` method?  Have you added some debugging code to verify it?

Comment: hmmmm, wait, oh I see, dude you are so smart! I should've remove TS then remove HS. If I remove HS element first, it would get me a null.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @VGR mentioned:
Are you certain that HS.get(a) never returns null in your compare method?

This is because that the TreeMap is based on HashMap to compare. If delete the HS value using HS.remove(a), whenever the treemap call HS.get(a) there will be a null as return value. which when called in compare for HS.get(a).compareTo will be null.compareTo, and this is the reason that throws an NullPointerException.

Comment: This is not an answer and should rather be a comment. Also, you are just repeating 1:1 what @VGR already said. If you are lacking reputation to comment, you should first gather reputation and not _abuse_ the answer-system to post a comment. Also note that answers should not contain questions that require a response from OP. See [answer], thanks.

Comment: @Zabuzard I'm not trying to get reputation to just answer my own post. VGR's comments pointed out the issue and did solved my problem, I just want to mark this post as answered. Anyway, audited. Thanks.